# Typed.js t.el is null

Tags: javascript, typeerror, typed.js

I'm trying to use type.js but I'm getting an error saying `TypeError: t.el is null`.

Even after following guides on Google or videos on YouTube and doing it the exact same way, the error is still there..

This is the html's head:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="typed.js-master/typed.js-master/lib/typed.min.js"></script>
<script src="general-behavior.js"></script>
```

The html's body:

```
<span class="typed"></span>
```

And the JavaScript code:

```
var typed = new Typed(".typed", {
  strings: [
  'Some <i>strings</i> with',
  'Some <strong>HTML</strong>',
  'Chars &times; &copy;'
  ],
});
```

Comment: Is this JavaScript code in `general-behavior.js`, or somewhere else?

Comment: @Ryan It's inside `general-behavior.js`